# Angularfire ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined

Tags: angularjs, firebase

contact.js --- this is angular file. i am trying to make my contact app .

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myContacts.contacts', ['ngRoute','firebase'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
    controller: 'ContactsCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('ContactsCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var rel = new Firebase('https://mycontact-app007.firebaseio.com/contacts');
  $scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(rel);
  console.log($scope.contacts);
}]);
```

Index.html - this the index file

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Mycontacts App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css">


</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="large-12 columns">
      <h1>myContact</h1>
      <hr>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div ng-view></div>
 </div>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="contacts/contacts.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

showing ReferenceError- Firebase is not defined
    at new  (contacts.js:13)
i am trying to make CURD operation app

Comment: Have you run bower install (and share your bower.json contents)?  Can you check to make sure `bower_components/firebase/firebase.js` is a valid file?

Comment: yes it is a valid file.

Comment: Why do u have some references to lib and some to bower_components?